# Why isn't Await blocking the next line of code?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, axios

I'm using an async function to start a server, check if the url returns `200`, and then run my tests, but my `checkUrl` function doesn't complete before running the next line of code.

I'm using the `axios` package to ping the url for the status code and I've been trying several variations of async/await and `Promise.resolve()`.

```
function checkUrl(url) {
  console.log(`Checking for ${url}`);

  return axios
    .get(url)
    .then(function(res) {
      const message = `${url} is status code: ${res.status}`;

      return res;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Will check again in 5 seconds");
      setTimeout(() => {
        return checkUrl(url);
      }, 5000);
    });
}

async function init() {
  let val;

  console.log("Running tests:::");
  // start server in react-integration directory
  shell.exec("BROWSER=none yarn start", {
    cwd: "sampleIntegration/react-integration",
    async: true
  });
  // check server has started
  val = await checkUrl("http://localhost:3000");

  console.log(`value from checkUrl promise: ${val}`);
}
```

I'm expecting the val variable to be the message returned from the `Promise.resolve()` in my `checkUrl` function.

`val` is coming back undefined.

Comment: The value is coming back `undefined` in both cases or only for the error case?

Comment: `shell.exec` is asynchronous, so when you call `checkurl` the server may not yet be available, thus causing `axios.get` to go into the catch branch. From there, you don't return anything, thus the final result is undefined

Comment: the console.log only gets run once after the catch block logs.
```Checking for http://localhost:3000
Will check again in 5 seconds
value from checkUrl promise: undefined```
Once the promise resolves, I get
```http://localhost:3000 is status code: 200``` 
but the line below the function has already run.

Comment: And I'm also not sure, wheter axios resolves or rejects when the http Status Code is != 2xx

Comment: The `return` inside the `setTimeout` doesn't do, what you probably think it does. This block is completely unrelated to the result of the catch block. In fact, your catch block does not have any result, yet `val == undefined`.

Comment: My desired outcome is to 
1. Start the server locally
2. Check the url status code returns 200
3. Run my tests
Any suggestions for what to put in place to make sure these operations run in order?

Comment: The setTimeout is adding strange behavior. If I remove it and just call checkUrl(url) recursively, then I get the desired effect. I just don't want to call checkUrl an extraordinary amount of times before it resolves.

Comment: @ChrisSchuhmacher That's not "strange" behaviour, that's how it is defined. If you don't use timeout, but just call `checkUrl` inside the catch block, the result of the catch block is the promise returned by the recursive call of `checkUrl`.  To understand, why this does not work with the given use of `setTimeout` you'll need to understand what the callstack and eventqueue is in javascript. It may be a bit confusing in the beginning

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Hope it helps others.
```.catch(err => {
            console.log('Will try again in 5 seconds');
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)).then(() => {
                return checkUrl(url);
            });```

Comment: @ChrisSchuhmacher You realize, that's exaclty the answer I posted below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, the `setTimeout` in the catch block. This is asynchronous, but the catch block immediately returns. As it does not have anything to return, it returns undefined. To resolve this (and also keep your desired behaviour of waiting) you could do something like this:

```
function checkUrl(url) {
  console.log(`Checking for ${url}`);

  return axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      const message = `${url} is status code: ${res.status}`;
      return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Will check again in 5 seconds');
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
         setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
      }).then(() => checkUrl(url));
    });
}
```

This will make a Promise which resolves after 5 seconds and on resolve it calls checkUrl.

Comment: Nice work @derpirscher. I didn't see your answer, but it looks like we are on the same page. Thank you for your assistance!